# The type [nameHere] registered for extension '[extensionHere]' could not be loaded

Tags: .net, wcf, web-config, jsonp, wcf-extensions

I've been learning and building JSONP Web services using WCF on fx3.5.  You can read some of the trials I had at [.NET ASMX - Returning Pure JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903022/net-asmx-returning-pure-json) I finally got a sample running but now I am I am dove tailing it into my app.

- RivWorks.Web - the web site - located at http://dev.example.com
- RivWorks.Web.Service - the new JSONP services - located in http://dev.example.com/services/ - the web.config for the services reside here.

The web.config for the service:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="JsonpServiceBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="RivWorks.Web.Service.CustomerService">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="customBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="jsonpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="JsonpServiceBehavior"
                  contract="RivWorks.Web.Service.ICustomerService" />
      </service>
      <service name="RivWorks.Web.Service.NegotiateService">
          <endpoint address=""
                  binding="customBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="jsonpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="JsonpServiceBehavior"
                  contract="RivWorks.Web.Service.INegotiateService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="jsonpBinding" >
          <jsonpMessageEncoding />
          <httpTransport manualAddressing="true"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>    
    <extensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="jsonpMessageEncoding"
             type="RivWorks.Web.Service.JSONP.JsonpBindingExtension
                 , RivWorks.Web.Service
                 , Version=1.0.0.0
                 , Culture=neutral
                 , PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      </bindingElementExtensions>
    </extensions>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I am getting the following error and I've tried everything I can think of to fix it.  Found a few typos (Sevice instead of Service) sprinkled throughout my code.  I am using the sample code found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716898.aspx).  Here is the error:

```
Configuration Error Description:** An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The type 'RivWorks.Web.Service.JSONP.JsonpBindingExtension
                , RivWorks.Web.Service
                , Version=1.0.0.0
                , Culture=neutral
                , PublicKeyToken=null' registered for extension 'jsonpMessageEncoding' could not be loaded.

Source Error:

Line 58:  <customBinding>
Line 59:      <binding name="jsonpBinding">
Line 60:          <jsonpMessageEncoding />
Line 61:          <httpTransport manualAddressing="true" />
Line 62:      <binding>

Source File: C:\RivWorks\dev\services\web.config    Line: 60

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3603; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what else I can check?  There is a DLL called RivWorks.Web.Service.dll, it is being built and copied to the web site's bin directory.  The services Web.config is being copied to the web site's Services directory.  I don't have anything conflicting in the web site's web.config.  I've checked all spelling problems.

Comment: This is definitely not an official answer, but I just wanted to share some frustration I had with this exact problem: In IIS I have Site A, which hosts Application A (App_A). I then have a virtual directory hosting Application B (App_B), under Site A as well. App_A is implementing a custom extension similar to above. App_B's web.config was inheriting this custom extension from App_A's web.config. This was throwing the exact error being described here. This was totally my fault for not configuring it correctly. I just wanted to share that with everyone. Not sure if it is answer worthy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is the dll (RivWorks.Web.Service.dll) in the build output?

Next, try (for the "jsonpMessageEncoding" extension):

```
type="RivWorks.Web.Service.JSONP.JsonpBindingExtension, RivWorks.Web.Service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
```

Note the different spacing both in terms of `" , "` and carriage returns.

After that, I would treble check the string. Write a console exe that references the dll you need (RivWorks.Web.Service), and output:

```
Console.WriteLine(
     typeof(RivWorks.Web.Service.JSONP.JsonpBindingExtension)
     .AssemblyQualifiedName);
```

That is the string you want in the xml, verbatim. Don't include any extra whitespace in this string.

Comment: Ran the console app and the string came back exactly like I have it.  Captured it in a string var, inspected it, copied it, pasted it into my services web.config and still the same error.  Other thoughts?

Comment: And yes, the DLL is in the build output.  I use BeyondCompare to move from my local machine project area to my localhost directory.  Also, from there it goes to the Dev directory on the Dev server (via BeyondCompare).  I check each step of the way and I can see the newest build each time.

Comment: I tried having it all on one line like you show and it made no difference.  :(

Comment: Also, the error message says "can't load" which, to me, means it can find it, just not load it.  Scrubbing my code once again.  I really need to understand everything in the JsonpBehavior, JsonpBindingElement, JsonpBindingExtension & JsonpEncoderFactory classes...

Comment: After renaming the Class and stripping extra white space out it is finally working.  Mayhaps something stuck in IIS cache.  WIll investigate that tomorrow.  Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: any solution and reasons of error ?? solution is renaming classes ??

Comment: @alhambraeidos my memory is hazy after a year, but it *sounds* that way

Comment: @alhambraeidos simply tidying up the data available in the original message to be formatted correctly, and to *exactly* match the classes as defined.

Comment: +1 this simple command really did the job!!!!  If you're using .NET4 make sure you use the full profile and not the client profile when running the reflection.  For me I had issues until I changed.

Comment: What solved it for me is making sure the dll was in the output directory. Once I rebuilt the solution, it was fine :)