# Cannot call Webmethod from JQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webmethod

I cannot call webmethod from jquery. I think its about web.config file. How can i set web.config file for web services and webmethod?

Comment: Doing just a spot check on his answers, I didn't see anything worth marking as an answer. Might just be me, but perhaps he could provide what he did in some of those questions.

Comment: Ok guys, come down please :) I did check my questions and mark some of answers as an "answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have this code?

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "Services/MyService.svc/Service",
            type: "GET",
            context: document.body,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                // do something
            }
        });
```

note that **contentType** part is critical.

If you do, check Firebug for exact error that gets thrown in the "Net" tab.
Normally, people have different problems depending on service type - ASP.NET asmx vs. WCF svc. For asmx configuration, refer to [How to let an ASMX file output JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211348/how-to-let-an-asmx-file-output-json) . For wcf, you need to set up web.config to allow web scripting, like so:

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
```

and then later configure the service to use that behavior:

```
  <services>
    <service name="MyProject.Services.MyService">
      <endpoint address="/Services/MyService.svc" behaviorConfiguration="AspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyProject.Services.MyService"/>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: That's right! But i want to visual studio write these code automatically.

Comment: not possible - visual studio doesn't have any automation with the help of jQuery. you can however use ASP.NET AJAX with servicereference - then it will be generated automatically, with method names, parameters etc. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514961.aspx#sectionToggle1