# ASMX returning JSON always inside an xml tag

Tags: json, asmx

I have asmx services that return json strings. I use DataContractJsonSerializer class and the resulting json is fine.

When I call these services to consume in a web app, the response is always coming backencapsulated in an xml tag. Any ways to get rid of the xml and return only the json.

### Example response :

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
< string xmlns="http://whatever.net/">

{"Success":true,"Data":{"RoomList":[{"CreatedAt":"\/Date(1291192978793-0800)\/","GameTimeOut":0,"MatchPointingType":0,"MoveTimeOut":0,"Name":"Reterras numagona alantis","RoomID":44,"SFID":null,"StartingMatchPoints":0,"UpdateAt":null,"UserID":12},{"CreatedAt":"\/Date(1291115544347-0800)\/","GameTimeOut":0,"MatchPointingType":0,"MoveTimeOut":0,"Name":"12122","RoomID":43,"SFID":null,"StartingMatchPoints":0,"UpdateAt":null,"UserID":2},{"CreatedAt":"\/Date(1291115537413-0800)\/","GameTimeOut":0,"MatchPointingType":0,"MoveTimeOut":0,"Name":"12122","RoomID":42,"SFID":null,"StartingMatchPoints":0,"UpdateAt":null,"UserID":2}],"TotalCount":42}}

< / string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds similar to this question:

[How to let an ASMX file output JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211348/how-to-let-an-asmx-file-output-json)

Comment: I don't understand how this relates to my question

Comment: It sounds like you are doing the serialization yourself, and then the asmx service is wrapping your response in XML.  Instead, setup the web service to do the serialization for you.  I've updated the link in my post.  I must've grabbed the wrong URL, sorry for not double checking.