# JSON From ASMX Service

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, asmx

I'm trying to get a VB.NET ASMX web service to return raw JSON (without the .d). I've declared a plethora of attributes but still get XML back. The signature of my method is:

```
<WebInvoke(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, Method:="GET")>
<WebGet(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
<WebMethod()>
Public Function TryLogin(ByVal userName As String, ByVal passwordHash As String) As LoginResult
```

Am I missing a declaration?

**EDIT:** I've tried requesting via POST, but I still get XML.

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211348/how-to-let-an-asmx-file-output-json

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `<ScriptService>` attribute on the class.

Answer (score 0):

I think your web method needs to return an *object* type.

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute `ScriptService` on your web-service class.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line, on its own line, two spaces below your Imports statements:

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
```

and immediately above the remaining code.