# Problems with jquery and C# web service

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, web-services

Output from web service, "http://localhost:6833/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld":

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
[{"Name":"Pini","Age":"30","ID":"111"},{"Name":"Yaniv","Age":"31","ID":"Cohen"},{"Name":"Yoni","Age":"20","ID":"Biton"}]
</string>
```

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "Service1.asmx/HelloWorld", 
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            alert("Result: " + msg);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error: " + textStatus);
    }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When i run index.html in browser i get the Error alert.. Tried alot of things, but cant find out whats missing..

Comment: Only Error: error. But not sure how that function works, all new to this

Comment: Try this alert("Error: " + errorThrown); and tell me what you are getting.

Comment: Think so yes, tried: "http://localhost:6833/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld" and just "Service1.asmx/HelloWorld". The first one works fine in my browser.

Comment: try "~/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld"

Comment: Since the problem is with path, try "../../Service1.asmx/HelloWorld" or "/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld" or use the full path, you can latter change it to your domain name.

Comment: Thanks, tried alot of combinations, but same error every time, must be something else.

Answer (score 1):

your json in encapsulated in a xml string, i guess thats your problem.

EDIT:

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211348/how-to-let-an-asmx-file-output-json) post for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before your method.

```
 [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

below

```
 [WebMethod]
```