# Can't test return value of Web Service in ajax call

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have the following jQuery code:

```
var isUsernameAvailable = false;

function CheckUsername(uname) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "IsUsernameAvailable.asmx/IsAvailable",
            data: { username: uname },
            dataType: "text",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError
        });     // end ajax
    }   // end CheckUsername
    function OnSuccess(data) {            
        if (data == true) {    // WHY CAN'T I TEST THE VALUE
            isUsernameAvailable = true;
        } else {
            isUsernameAvailable = false;
            $('#error').append('Username not available');
        }
    }
    function OnError(data) {
        $('#error').text(data.status + " -- " + data.statusText);            
    }
```

And a simple Web Service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following     line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class IsUsernameAvailable : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public IsUsernameAvailable () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public bool IsAvailable(string username) {
        return (username == "xxx");
    }

}
```

I just can't read the return value from my web service. When I print out the value in the callback function (`data` parameter) I get `true` or `false` (note the preceding whitespace).

When I print out `data.d`, it says `undefined`. FYI, the web service method gets hit each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `dataType` specified as `text`.  This would lead me to believe that the response you're getting is actually a string and not a boolean value.  Switching the dataType to `json` would give you a Javascript object.

**Edit**: The reason for the parsererror is because the boolean that you are returning is actually a .NET boolean converted to a string.  When `.ToString()` ends up being called for the actual HTTP response, it ends up being `True` or `False`.  In JSON, boolean values are `true` or `false` (notice the casing).  When jQuery is trying to parse the response, it doesn't think it's a correct boolean and throws the error.

Depending on what ASP.NET flavor you are using, you have a few options.  If you're using MVC or the Web API, just return like this:

```
return Json(username == "xxx", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

If you aren't using either of those technologies, then it might be best to change your return type to a string and then call:

```
return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(username == "xxx");
```

You will need to import the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace for the previous code snippet to work.

Comment: I did what you suggested with `return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(username == "xxx");` and `dataType: "text"` and now in OnSuccess() I test for 'true' (string value) but nothing... The OnSuccess() does get hit, but none of the conditions.

Comment: @robotron - The `dataType` should not be text; it should be json.

Comment: @robotron - What is the **exact** data you are getting back from the server?

Comment: When I debug the WebService it shows it's returning either "true" or "false". What gets to the browser, I don't know.

Comment: @robotron - You should find out.  If using Firefox, download FireBug and you will be able to see.

Comment: I've dug up this (with Chrome): `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">false</string>` How can it be that it's sending back XML? I did everything as stated above.

Comment: @robotron - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211348/how-to-let-an-asmx-file-output-json.  If you can upgrade to MVC/Web API your life will be much more enjoyable.

Comment: It's easy to write out the value received from the web service, but to test against it... Impossible. Maybe I should do some basic research, I have a feeling I've got the whole thing wrong. Thank you, nevertheless.