# asp.net 3.5 webservice will not return JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, asmx, webmethod

I've done some searching online and can't seem to figure this out. How do I force the response to be just JSON?

**web.config**

```
<httpHandlers>
            <remove path="*.asmx" verb="*" />
            <add path="*.asmx" verb="*" validate="false"
                 type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, 
                 System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0,
                 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />

</httpHandlers>
```

**ajax**

```
function get_data() {            
            var objdata = new Object;
            objdata.tool = '1';
            objdata.product = 'Something';
            objdata.details = '9';
            objdata.bogus = 'should not pass validation';
            var server = 'http://crossdomainserver:87';
            var webMethod = '/LogInfo.asmx/LogInfo?';
            var url = server + webMethod + "tool=" + objdata.tool + "&" +
                "product=" + objdata.product + "&" +
                "details=" + objdata.details + "&" +
                "bogus=" + objdata.bogus;
            $('#url').html("<p>" + url + "</p>");

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#get').html("<p>" + data + "</p>");
                },
                error: function (e) {

                }
            });


            $('#result').html("<p>" + result.statusText + "</p>");
        }
```

**webservice**

```
' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class LogInfo
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
    Public Function LogInfo() As String
     'do database/error logic here
     Return jsonreturn.ToString
    End Function

    End Class
```

**response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"tool":"1","product":"Something","details":"9","user":"username","systime":"1/29/2013 10:20:50 AM","site":"Somewhere, AZ","team":"000000000","result":"1"}</string>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/211671/752527

Comment: @Hanlet jsonp uses a GET request. Cross domain requests can not be completed by POST per the Same Source Policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is not possible with `.asmx` you need to use `WCF` web service to return the data in json format.

Read this for [HTTP Programming with WCF and the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135976.aspx)

Comment: Do you mean jsonp is not possible with .asmx?

Comment: Yes, I meant this. If you can provide us a sample of `json` with `.asmx` please?