# C# json Webservice is wrapped in XML

Tags: c#, xml, json, web-services

this is a C# Webservice that produces json, but it's wrapped in XML.  Any easy way to address this on Server side code?  It's a simple website solution. Could something be missing from my web.config?

Many Thanks.

Update: One of the answers on here disappeared for some reason, but it was a good suggestion that I not serialize and retrun a json object. I'm not sure how to do that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public WebService()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();


[WebMethod]
    public string GetID(string id)
    {


        var json = "";
        var uid = from result in dc.GET_ID(id) select result;

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        json = jss.Serialize(uid);

        return json;
    }
```

Comment: Hi there, Do you want your results in JSON Format right...

Answer (score 0):

The deleted answer suggested first to use `ScriptMethod` or `ScriptService` attributes (i.e. `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]`).

That is the correct approach to return json from a web service in .NET.

See here for more info: [How to let an ASMX file output JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211348/how-to-let-an-asmx-file-output-json).

Comment: which of the answers on that post are you referring to? I wish I could find a complete example to work with. I'm hoping I don't have to construct the json string manually. Thank you!

Comment: Tried this with no luck.  [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetID(string id)

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? What version of ASP.NET?