# Kendo UI Grid with ASMX service: XML is returned instead of JSON

Tags: kendo-ui, asmx

I am using the following Kendo UI Grid to consume the ASMX service below. I have confirmed that the service is emmitting JSON if I use a standard JQuery ajax method but if I try to consume it with a kendo grid then I get this as the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfEmployeeCountByTypeModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />


$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "HRDashboardService.asmx/GetEmployeeCountByType",
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },
            schema: {
                data: "d",
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        FY: { type: "string" },
                        Month: { type: "string" },
                        AreaName: { type: "string" },
                        PFCName: { type: "string" },
                        OnRoll: { type: "number" }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        groupable: false,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true
        },
        columns: [{
            field: "FY",
            width: 20,
            title: "FY"
        },
        {
            field: "Month",
            width: 20,
            title: "Month"
        },
        {
            width: 20,
            field: "AreaName",
            title: "Area Name"
        },
        {
            width: 20,
            field: "PFCName",
            title: "PFC Name"
        },
        {
            field: "EmployeeType",
            width: 40,
            title: "Employee Type"
        },
        {
            width: 20,
            field: "OnRolls",
            title: "OnRolls"
        }]
    });
```

Here's my ASMX Service:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetEmployeeCountByType() As List(Of EmployeeCountByTypeModel)
    Dim results As List(Of EmployeeCountByTypeModel) = Nothing

    Try
        results = (From r In DbContext.SprocEmployeeCountByType
                       Select New EmployeeCountByTypeModel With { _
                            .AreaCode = r.AreaCode, _
                            .FY = r.FY, _
                            .AreaName = r.AreaName, _
                            .EmployeeType = r.EmployeeType, _
                            .Month = r.Month, _
                            .OnRoll = r.OnRoll, _
                            .PFCCode = r.PFCCode, _
                            .PFCName = r.PFCName _
                        }).ToList()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Return results
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also struggled with this and could not get an answer.
And here is what I found.
If you are still having the problem that is...

The following line of code must be uncommented in the webservice:

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
```

Be sure to add the following in the web.config file of the webservice inside

```
<webServices>
   <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet"/>
      <add name="HttpPost"/>
   </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Create a class like this that will contain the list of items and the row count:

```
Public Class UsersResult
    Private _Data As List(Of clsUsers_Item)
    Private _Total As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        _Data = Nothing
        _Total = 0
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(data As List(Of clsUsers_Item), total As Integer)
        _Data = data
        _Total = total
    End Sub

    Public Property Total() As Integer
        Get
            Return _Total
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Total = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Property Data() As List(Of clsUsers_Item)
        Get
            Return _Data
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of clsUsers_Item))
            _Data = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And the webservice's code:

```
<WebMethod(), ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function getUsers() As UsersResult
    'data will be the list of objects that you want to return
    Return New UsersResult(data, data.Count)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the network tab of the google developers tools to make sure that kendo grid datasource is indeed sending the request as a POST type and not GET.

This link describes why an asmx service might return xml instead of json...
[How to let an ASMX file output JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211348/how-to-let-an-asmx-file-output-json)

Comment: Yes I have confirmed that it is using a POST not a GET.