# asmx round trip json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, knockout.js, asmx

I am calling an asmx  webservice which returns `json (msg.d)` that is consumed properly by knockout.js. When I attempt to return the identical json to asmx, I get error messages. Is there something obvious I'm missing? ... `msg.d` is a well formed object array.

calling `storeGroupCategories(msg.d);` returns webservice error ...

> {"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: Baby+Books."

calling `storeGroupCategories(msg);` returns webservice error ...

> {"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: d."

**WebService**

```
public class kbo_inexcludecategories : WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public List<Group> GetIncludeExcludeJson()
    {
        var Groups =  new List<Group>();
        ShopAssistGroupHandler.getInExCategories(Groups);
        return Groups;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public GroupGuid StoreGroupCategories(List<InExCategory> inExCategories)
    {
        var inExString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inExCategories);
        var returnGuid = DataHandler.SaveGroupJsonString(inExString);
        return new GroupGuid(returnGuid);
    }
}
```

Associated json ...

```
var _url = "kbo-inexcludecategories.asmx/";
var _method = "GetIncludeExcludeJson";
var _jsonData = "{}";

function storeGroupCategories(groupCategories) {
    if(groupCategories != ""){
        showProgressBar("Storing Group Categories");
        getJsonData(_url, "StoreGroupCategories", groupCategories);
    }
}

function getGroupMatrix() {
    showProgressBar("Loading Group Categories");
    getJsonData(_url, _method, _jsonData);
}

function getJsonData(url, method, jsonData) {
    var myUrl = url + method;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myUrl,
        data: jsonData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false, //blocks window close
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError
    });
}

function onSuccess(msg) {

    // Hide the fake progress indicator graphic.
    hideProgressBar("");
    if(msg.d.hasOwnProperty("Guid")) {
        saveGroupGuid(msg.d);
    }
    else {
        storeGroupCategories(msg.d);
        //showGroupAccordion(msg.d);
        //OpenAdvancedDialog();
    }
}
```

json sample ...

```
"{\"groups\":[{\"__type\":\"group\",\"id\":1488,\"name\":\"Baby Books\",\"categories\":
[{\"__type\":\"groupcategory\",\"id\":152,\"name\":\"Activity Books\",\"value\":\"Included\"},
{\"__type\":\"groupcategory\",\"id\":167,\"name\":\"Bedtime and Dreams\",\"value\":\"Excluded\"}
```

Comment: POssibly, you need to set teh response type to JSON http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211348/how-to-let-an-asmx-file-output-json

Answer (score 0):

To begin with I think you need to pass your json in like this:

```
storeGroupCategories(msg.d)
```

But within this function you also need to create valid json parameters to the post, which would look like this:

```
getJsonData(_url, "StoreGroupCategories", "{ inExCategories: " + groupCategories + " }");
```

I would also change your signature to the following, so groups matches the argument you are passing across:

```
public GroupGuid StoreGroupCategories(List<InExCategory> groups)
```

If you put a break point in the web page method, you will see exactly what is coming across, and check that it is what you are expecting.

Comment: Still got error, when I added JSON.stringify to object in call
getJsonData(_url, "StoreGroupCategories",  "{ inExCategories: " + JSON.stringify(groupCategories) + " }");
 I got a simpler error .... ":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027groups\u0027.","

Comment: You shouldn't need to stringify, just try it without.

Comment: I did that first & got ...
{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: object

Comment: Ok, there must be some kind of json serialize issue before you send it across.

Can you debug and check that it resembles something like:

data: '{"groups":[{"__type\":"group","id":1488,"name":"Baby Books","categories":
[{"__type":"groupcategory","id" ...'

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the right track. I had to make name changes:
    public GroupGuid StoreGroupCategories(List<InExCategory> groups)
        {
            var inExString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groups);

and

     "{ groups: " + groupCategories + " }" where groupCategories was stringified.

All is well with the world.