# ASP.NET Web service application send data as JSON

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, http

I wrote a "ASP.NET Web Service application" some time ago in .NET 3.5 framework.

Now the number of requests to this app grows a lot and I started to have real problems with server's bandwith.

My first idea for lighten the app it was change transfer language for data from HTTP to JSON.

Is this easy to do and realizable?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211348/how-to-let-an-asmx-file-output-json

Comment: Sorry for the dupplication. I'm going to see this answer!

Comment: No problem. I think with search terms like "asmx json output" you'll get more results. ASMX is the name of ASP.NET Web Services.

Comment: or you could switch to `REST` based services.

Comment: @Amit the answer to _"How can I change the output of an existing implementation"_ is not _"By reimplementing the whole shebang in a different framework"_. I do agree that for new development of web services you should pick something like WCF or ASP.NET WebAPI.

Comment: @CodeCaster - that was just another suggestion to move forward.

Comment: try read on "how to optimize web service" for example : [Improving Web Services Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647786.aspx) || [Web Service optimization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12892/Web-Service-optimization)

Answer (score -1):

Yes,

That is much appreciated one, you will be feel real difference of JSON data that comes from server. change your service as REST.