# Ajax call to asp.net web method doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I am new to ajax and javascript.

I have the following web method in a page called people.aspx in the root of my web porject:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string RenderDetails()
{
    return "Is it working?";
}
```

I'm attempting to access the web method via an Ajax call from the people.aspx page. I have the following ajax call on the click event of a div:

```
$("div.readonly").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      async:false,
        url: "people.aspx/RenderDetails",                   
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
            alert("attempting contact");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("I think it worked.");
        },
        failure: function (msg) { alert("Sorry!!! "); }
    });

    alert("Implement data-loading logic");
});
```

I'm not receiving any errors in the javascript console, however, the ajax call also does not hit the web method. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What debug console of your browsers says?

Comment: From memory standard 'webmethod' is a GET transaction, your AJAX request is POST. Try change AJAX to GET, or change your webmethod to POST.

Comment: did you decorate your sevice with `ScriptService` attribute and use `ScriptMethod` to decorate your method? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211348/how-to-let-an-asmx-file-output-json

Comment: Post your aspx page content here.

Comment: Thanks for all the information guys, the POST change to GET did the trick for me. Apologies for the late reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change the type to `GET` not `POST` (this is probably why your webpage isn't getting hit).  Also your `failure` [parameter is incorrect](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), it should be `error`.  Expand it to include all parameters (it will provide more information).  In short, change your entire AJAX query to this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async:false,
    url: "people.aspx/RenderDetails",                   
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
        alert("attempting contact");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("I think it worked.");
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
        alert("Sorry!!! ");  // Insert breakpoint here
    }
});
```

In your browser, debug the error function.  The parameters (particularly jqXHR) contain a LOT of information about what has failed.  If you are still having more problems, give us the information from jqXHR (error string, error codes, etc).

Comment: Thanks very much for the information. Changing from POST to GET did the trick. Apologies for the late reply, got side tracked with other projects.