# AngularJS ASMX Return with ng-repeat blank

Tags: html, angularjs, json, web-services, asmx

Hey everyone I'm extremely new to AngularJS and I have an issue with my ng-repeat showing blank table rows on the page. So, I'm calling a asmx web service to return a JSON Serialized string of simple work queue information. When I try to display it to a table on the page all the rows are blank.

WebService Method:

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void GetMainWorkQueueInformationJson(string userName, string status)
    {
        try
        {
            var info = incidentManagerDal.GetMainWorkQueueInformation(userName, status);
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(info);
            logger.Info("Gathered Working Queue Information.", new object[] { "Success" });
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(json);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
<div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>IM#</th>
                    <th>Requirements Received Date</th>
                    <th>Planned Implementation Date</th>
                    <th>Dev Assigned</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in queue track by $index">
                    <td>{{x.IMNumber}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.RequirementsReceivedDate}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.PlannedImplementationDate}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.DevAssigned}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Title}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Module/Controller js:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('inserturl', {
    params: { userName: "name", status: "working" }
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    $scope.queue = response.data;
}).catch(function (response) {
    console.error('Error occurred:', response.status, response.data);
}).finally(function () {
    console.log("Task Finished.");
});
```

I'm not sure what I'm. Trying to understand the basics of calling webservices to get information from and displaying that data.
Appreciate any help.

Update:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{"RequestID":1052,"IMNumber":"dsdsad","CMNumber":"","RequirementsReceivedDate":"2017-04-20T15:04:02.423","PlannedImplementationDate":"2017-04-20T15:04:02.423","DevAssigned":"name","Title":"dsadsada","Description":"dsadsadsa","Comments":"dsadsadsafdsfdsfdsfds","Status":"Working","RequestedBy":"requestname","DoesNotRequireCMR":null,"DeveloperTime":0},{"RequestID":1053,"IMNumber":"fdsfdsfds","CMNumber":"","RequirementsReceivedDate":"2017-04-20T15:04:39.75","PlannedImplementationDate":"2017-04-20T15:04:39.75","DevAssigned":"name","Title":"fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfds","Description":"dsadsadsa","Comments":"dsadsadsadsa","Status":"Working","RequestedBy":"dsadsadsa","DoesNotRequireCMR":null,"DeveloperTime":999},{"RequestID":1054,"IMNumber":"dasdas","CMNumber":"","RequirementsReceivedDate":"2017-04-20T18:22:41.513","PlannedImplementationDate":"2017-04-20T18:22:41.513","DevAssigned":"name","Title":"dsadasdasda","Description":"dsadasdas","Comments":null,"Status":"Working","RequestedBy":"dsdasdasd","DoesNotRequireCMR":null,"DeveloperTime":0}]</string>
```

Update:

Modified webservice method to write directly back to remove the xml wrapping the json object.

Comment: check if the details are returned and if yes, make sure you are accessing the correct result set (`respose.data` may be) then, make sure the property keys are correct. they might be in lowercase.

Comment: How can I validate details are returned?

Comment: just `console.log(response)` them

Comment: I added an update of what it outputs to the console.

Comment: aghhh it's enclosed in `xml`. thats the issue you want to fix. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211348/how-to-let-an-asmx-file-output-json

Comment: You're amazing sir. thank you for the help and link.